# Creating a model instance on post save

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempting to create an instance of Car when a user creates an instance of model House.

Models.py

```
class House(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    makemodel = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def create_car(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        car = Car.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_car, sender=House)   #have to figure out how to have multiple senders
```

When I go into the admin and create an instance of the House model for any user, I get the following error.

```
"Cannot assign "<House: jason>": "Car.user" must be a "User" instance."
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to pass in a value for `makemodel` as this is not optional in your `Car` model; otherwise you will get another error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass as `user` argument User instance, but in `create_car` since sender is `House`, instance argument has type `House`.

You can do something like this:

```
def create_car(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        car = Car.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'].user)
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks so much. I'll accept this as the answer as soon as SO lets me (in about 10 minutes).